# When we say 'The probability that a red ball is picked is 0.5', what type of subordinate clause is being used?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

We usually say "What is the probability that XXX...?" or "The probability that XXX is 0.5". One example would be in this sentence:

> The probability that a red ball is picked is 0.5.

(We may also say "the probability of something".)

I was wondering which type of subordinate clause we are using here with the phrase "*that a red ball is picked*". Is it a noun clause, adjective clause, or adverbial clause?
None seem correct to me, and I'm really confused.

I think an explanation, as well as a second example using the same clause, would be useful.

Comment: But it’s also a restrictive relative clause, isn’t it? Or is that another classification scheme?

Comment: @Xanne No: it cannot be a relative clause because there is no element in the _that_ clause that is anaphorically linked to the head noun "probability". Note also the impossibility of replacing "that" with the relative pronoun "which".

Comment: @JohnLawler But content clauses don't function as objects. In your last example the _that_ clause is just as much a complement of "reported" as it is of "report" in your first example.

Comment: Report verbs (3-place verbs with Source, Trajector, and Goal arguments that allow _that_-clauses as trajector arguments) have trajector DOs, whether they're clauses or not. And being a complement of one predicate doesn't preclude being a complement of another, depending on what you take the predicate to be.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with what you say. In my experience the term 'trajector' is used in connection with preposition phrases. There is no evidence to support a claim that content clauses (or any kind of clause) can be regarded as grammatical objects.

Answer (score 4):

> *The probability* [*that a red ball is picked*] *is 0.5.*

Preliminary point: I would advise against using the terms 'noun clause', 'adjective clause' and 'adverb clause'. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

The bracketed element is a declarative content clause functioning as complement of "probability".  Note that content clauses are the default kind of finite subordinate clause. As its name suggests, the clause is simply selected for its semantic content.

Another similar example is *The probability* [*that he was elsewhere at the time*] *was accepted.*

Despite the presence of the subordinator "that", it cannot be a relative clause because there is no element that is anaphorically linked to the head noun "probability". Note also the impossibility of replacing "that" with the relative pronoun "which".

Comment: What would it be called if the clause were changed to 'of a red ball being picked'?

Comment: @HippoSawrUs That would be a **preposition phrase**. Its function would be the same as that of the _that_ clause, i.e. complement of "probability".

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if that was a thing in descriptive grammar. IDK what all a *complement* is yet, in its various grammars.